# Python lib psutil: how to get exit status with wait()

Tags: python, subprocess, exit-code

I am executing a 3rd party application using Subprocess Popen with many arguments

```
myprocess=Popen(['executionlist','with','arguments'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
myprocess.communicate()
```

getting my tuple for stdout and err, the 3rd party app starts in background so I get its pid in the stdout...[if I try to run in forground, it throws "Error opening terminal: unknown"]
I am using psutil to track all this forking and monitor it using,

```
EXITCODE=psutil_obj.wait(timeout=xxx)
```

the application sends different exit codes, that I need to access in EXITCODE but as I am running it in different python script it always gives me 'None' value....

As per,
https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation
"Wait() for process termination and if the process is a children of the current one also return the exit code, else None."

Is there anyway I can access the exit code from the independent process id, not specifically forked by Popen?

Comment: what starts the 3rd party app? Can you inject a shell command?

Comment: Python method is starting the app, I don't want to inject shell as my arguments are variable and I need to handle bufsize.
My only concern is where shall I get the exit status, as the third party app it self start another process in background, so myprocess.communicate().pid and the actual process that I have to monitor is different

Comment: What is the 3rd party app that starts the child process that you want to get exit status of? Can you instruct it to report the exit status of its child? If not; then you probably won't be able to get the exit status by any means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs you quoted tell you flat out that `psutil` can only get the exit code "if the process is a children of the current one".

And that's the real key here–it's not whether the process was launched by `Popen`, but whether it's a child of the current process.*

This is fundamental to the Unix process model. Parents must wait for their children. You can't get someone else to wait for them (except by reparenting them). If the parent is still running, it has to be the one to reap them. If the parent is not running anymore, either the child was already a zombie, or it gets reparented to the parent's parent or to init/launchd/etc. or gets orphaned (the details are different on different systems and different situations). There is no case in which some other process can wait for them.

On top of that, once the parent calls `wait` (which `Popen.communicate` does), the process—and its entry in the system process table, with its retcode—may not even exist anymore.

---

* That being said, even if you weren't going across processes, it's a bad idea to mix `subprocess` with lower-level APIs like `os` or `psutil`. If you create a `Popen` object, you must call its `wait` method, or something else that does it for you—like `communicate`. And once you do that, it may not exist anymore. If you want to use `os.wait`, do it with a process created by the fork/spawn/etc. methods in `os`. If you want to use `psutil.wait`, you can do it with a process created by `os`, or by `psutil.Popen`, but not by `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Only parent can wait for a child therefore *a process can't become a zombie if it has no alive parent*. Otherwise there is no point in keeping the process info if nobody can wait for it. If parent dies either the process is already a zombie (it is dead and parent hasn't reaped it) or the process is alive (can't be zombie) so it becomes an orphan temporarily.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You're right, technically if the parent quits without reaping the child it's _already_ a zombie. I'm trying to describe things from the point of view of what you see when trying to wait from a different process. You will always see only zombies and orphans, never children. I'll try to rewrite it to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks abarnert and Sebastian for describing this for me, if I implement Subprocess.Popen and do communicate() with child, how do I get the retcode, I find Popen.returncode attribute?
Also my main concern is I want to execute this process and move on without waiting for it to complete because the next process is the real finisher....and I am calling these process as a part of def methods(): and not as a script execution....in that case which will be my parent process?

Comment: @creativeDrive: For your first question, yes, after `communicate` returns, `returncode` is guaranteed to have the retcode. For the second, it's complicated. The only way to "execute this process and move on" but still get the retcode later, is to keep the `Popen` objects around and call `communicate` or `wait` on them later. But without knowing more about your code or its intended goal, it's hard to say more. When are you trying to get the retcode? Whenever that is, can you just `wait(0)` or not? Or do you want a callback every time one of them finishes? Is this in an event-driven program?

Answer (score 0):

After going back and forth on a few comments, I suspect you're actually looking to do something like this:

In your main program, "fire and forget" some background processes. But later, in the same program, whenever each of those processes actually finishes, run some code that gets access to the process's return code (and maybe output).

---

Here's an example that does that, by using a watcher thread for each background process:

```
import subprocess
import threading

def doit(arglist, callback):
    def threadfunc():
        p = subprocess.Popen(arglist, 
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
        callback(out, err, p.returncode)
    t = threading.Thread(target=threadfunc)
    t.start()
```

---

This has two obvious limitations, but ultimately they're the exact same multiplexing problems you deal with when trying to, e.g., talk to lots of machines over the internet at the same time, and they have the same solutions.

First, having hundreds of threads is bad. They're not *doing* anything, but they still have big stacks that eat up your virtual memory space (especially bad in 32-bit Python) and take up space in the kernel scheduler table (especially bad in older Unixes). Fortunately, if you don't care about Windows, you can get around that the same way you do with network code: toss the subprocess pipes into a `select` or `poll` loop. Or, if you *do* care about Windows, or just don't want to write your own `select` loop, find a framework that does all the heavy lifting for you. If you [search PyPI for "subprocess"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=subprocess&submit=search) you will find some options specific to `subprocess`. If you're already using an event-driven network or GUI framework like Twisted or Qt, it may well have its own way to do this built in (e.g., see [Using Processes](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html) for Twisted).

Second, your `callback` gets called in some arbitrary background thread, and has no way to propagate a return value or exception to the rest of your code except by mutating some shared value. Which means you're now dealing with all the usual headaches of shared-data threading, even though you never asked to do so. All of the usual ways to improve that situation—`queue`, `concurrent.futures`, etc.—apply here as well.

---

Of course if you're lucky, you only have a dozen or so processes running at a time (so the first problem isn't a problem), and all you want to do in the callback is, say, to print or log some data (so the second problem isn't a problem).